# Is there a simple way to use a component with both static and dynamically changing props?

Tags: vuejs3

Say I have a component that takes a prop, does some calculations and then displays the result. A simple version could look like this.

#### CustomComponent.vue

```
<template>
  {{ calculated }}
</template>

<script setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    value: Number,
  })

  const calculated = props.value // Actually more complicated in real life
</script>
```

Now in the parent, I have two use-cases.

1. I want to use the component to display individual instances
2. I want to dynamically reuse the same instance with changing props

#### App.vue

```
<template>
// some code
  <custom-component :value="4"></custom-component>
  <custom-component :value="5"></custom-component>

  <custom-component :value="value"></custom-component>
</template>

<script setup>
  import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent.vue'
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  // This value will be changed dynamically in the code
  const value = ref(null);
</script>
```

With this setup, only the individual instances will be displayed. Inside the dynamic instance, the initial value for `value` will not change dynamically.

I have found a way to handle both use cases, but it somehow feels wrong. For it to work, I have to change the `script` of the CustomComponent to the following. *Note that I am using a `function` since the original code uses a more complex logic inside the function.*

```
<script setup>
  import { watch } from 'vue'

  const props = defineProps({
    value: Number,
  })

  let calculated = null
  function init() {
    // Actually more complicated in real life
    calculated = props.value
  }
  init()

  watch(
    () => props.value,
    () => init()
  )
</script>
```

Here is a working example in [Vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlVMtu2zAQ/JWFeogTRCLy6EWwgxS9Fz0UvcQ5SBQds6ZIgqRkGIb/vUtScWi7rh1YF4n7mtnVLF/W2Teti75jWZmNHWu1qBx7mkqAcZ9XWofPcKBKuopLZgZTMBq13B6HKJEY0ERVq5Vk0kHZV6Jjk2n2OM2exmTrOBn/9Wj8mOwi+nNK6SyGfV47Cc9UcLpAtIh6h5h3vhz6zgi/x/D7f4X/9u4S1msIgbDZ7BSrDZCT/Yf3pTPYs8es9I96S/zhY5IIAY+WGq4dWOa6qAeOLIyDNRg2gw3MjGrhCjV0lTi/b/uI7oJsLV5uGOqDkYJ1w2gmvtxIdkJcew4RFfGy2yzWzNtKF3+skqjVtc+eDg47zXDEsTEclx9WiR9z57QtCaGNxLSGCd6bQjJHpG7JM4YR00nHW5Y3qn1+KB6KR9Jw61JzwWyb1zg3ywwWmWa3CYzjs9UZUENkQLi7jxCDLRdVbT3GQW2CgD0zuWGyYYaZc1vaS0vb2nMdtObRUZ4bHLjgcmH3Zk1tmPPLO8nLeg7VfKnXiLijjsPLqOE9WLcSfh/qii7ejOpk44WvTAkrJoRa4orgntFK0M4nNrhsY0TuPyXpZeXofE/UH0rVRmmLSm3YDBfnpz+NBuEFEZfwo2trZsKf3KCO/ZuQLyeeGAW/5tzCUpmFhZkyoKRYga6s5fIN3JwFdLRS9kEo6XYS2RXxurgIuVnJquVYGwnQeSXfUgY25NzchLYF2+Pg9zd4wiBHwy00uobJU8pvkPrgGEaIz/F+gjvenjhXgBtyWY+1cnPoLENIy9KejrY06yR1XEngkjskPrD+H+XAN4ZHtulUjg0l2t+zknbTS3Fzm4XVxtWJO5a9/gWklnBY).
**Is there a better way or a best practice to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that needs to be done to make `props` reactive.  In Component.vue you can use `{{ value }}` by itself and it will rerender with the new prop value.

[Playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

The only other thing I can point out is that you shouldn't call your custom component `<component>` because it's already a reserved name for the [special built-in element](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component) provided by Vue

Comment: In the actual application there are complicated calculations going on. The sample code here should only show the principle issue. Also the actual component is not called `component`, but thanks, I will edit the question.

Comment: make `calculated` a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html).  Computed properties rerun whenever their dependencies update.  So if `props.value` updates, so will `calculated`, thus also causing a rerender of `{{ calculated }}` in your template